# Cannot send mail through AWS SES using SQL Server 2016 on Windows Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am setting up a new SQL Server in AWS, and am going through the motions of configuring it. I'm working on setting Database mail, which should be relatively simple, but something isn't working right.

In AWS SES, I have my entire domain verified and also an email address verified. I have the SMTP endpoint from the dashboard, and also a set of SMTP credentials created.

On the SQL Server side, the screenshot below is the configuration. I have tried ports 25 (which i know is blocked, but I tried it anyways), 465, 587, and 2587.

[image]

[image]

On AWS, my Security group for outbound is wide open, All port ranges to 0.0.0.0/0

The Network ACL  outbound rule is also wide open.

I have to be missing something basic. Any help?

Comment: When you say, setting up a new SQL Server on AWS, is this via RDS or via an EC2 instance?

Comment: On EC2 there's restrictions to using Port 25 (which can be removed), however, ports 465 and 587 are unrestricted so you might want to try those. https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshoot-smtp.html

Comment: Don't waste time trying to make it work with port 465. SQL Server uses an external .NET Framework based process, DatabaseMail.exe, to actually connect and deliver mail messages to MTAs. That uses the [`SmtpClient` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient) which only supports encrypted mail transport using Explicit SSL (`STARTTLS`), but not Implicit SSL (SMTP over SSL/TLS), so it will work on STARTTLS-enabled services on port 25 and 587, but it can not establish a TLS connection when connecting to services on port 465.

Comment: I guess it's worth asking... if you're trying to connect to the SMTP endpoint `email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` is your instance actually in us-east-2?

Comment: Also, if you want to use port 25 for outbound SMTP you'll need to do more than allow it in your EC2 security groups and network ACLs, you [need to fill in a request form](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/).

Comment: What version of Windows Server are you running on? Have you enabled TLS 1.2 for client connections at the server level in the Registry? Have you enabled TLS 1.2 at the .NET Framework 4.x level in the Registry? Despite databasemail.exe being a .NET Framework 3.5-based program, have you installed .NET Framework 4.5.2 on the server and configured the databasemail.exe.config file to use `<startup> <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" /> </startup>`?